# SwiftUI How to make ForEach with Dict with array of custom objects auto update

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I have a dict with arrays of custom classes, defined like this:

```
var coupons: [String: [Coupon]]
```

And I put them into a ForEach like this:

```
List {
                        
        ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
                Section(header: Text(key)) {
                    ForEach(couponDict[key] ?? [], id: \.id) { coupon in
                            Button(ifexpiredString(date: coupon.date)+coupon.data[1]) {
                                     let coupons = UserDefaults.standard.coupons
                                     let couponIndex = coupons.firstIndex(of: coupon)
                                     self.currentview = "Coupon"+String(couponIndex!)
                            }.foregroundColor(ifexpired(date: coupon.date) ? Color.gray : ifexpireing(date: coupon.date))
                   }
           }
     }
}
```

I've read many answers on making an auto-updating `ForEach` or `List`, but none using a dictionary with an array of custom objects stored under each key. Worse, I'm drawing `couponDict` from `UserDefaults`. How can I make this `List` or `ForEach` auto-update itself?

Comment: Just to say, dictionaries are not ordered. So don't be surprised if things go around the place when the dictionary is changed.

Comment: Also, why did you remove the `swift` tag? It's relevant to the question because the code is in Swift. It also helps Stack Overflow highlight the code correctly because it knows the language.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention - I sort the dictionary using `map` by alphabetical order so that doesn't happen. And I'll add the swift tag back.

Comment: Yeah dictionary really isn't the way to go. Instead try an array of a custom `struct` that contains `[Coupon]`

Comment: @KunalKatiyar "sort the dictionary using `map`" wdym? Dictionaries aren't sortable

Comment: Oh no, I meant the keys of the dictionary, from which I call the respective array in `couponDict`.

Comment: Maybe it’s time to introduce a view model class and move mod of the logic to this class.

Comment: There’s some relevant code missing. Make sure that Coupon is a struct. Are you using a ‘@State’ property wrapper? If you want something that updates and reflects UserDefaults, look into @AppStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
List {
    ForEach(Array(coupons.keys), id: \.self) { key in 
    // or ForEach(coupons.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in 
        Section(header: Text(key)) {
            ForEach(coupons[key] ?? [], id: \.id) { coupon in
                Button(ifexpiredString(date: coupon.date)+coupon.data[1]) {
                    let coupons = UserDefaults.standard.coupons
                    let couponIndex = coupons.firstIndex(of: coupon)
                    self.currentview = "Coupon"+String(couponIndex!)
                }.foregroundColor(ifexpired(date: coupon.date) ? Color.gray : ifexpireing(date: coupon.date))
            }
        }
    }
}
```